# GlassFish - How to get datasource from OSGI bundle

Tags: java, glassfish, osgi, apache-felix

I have this Apache Felix activator which gets data source service:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.Properties;
import org.DX_57.osgi.SH_27.api.SessionHandle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.osgi.framework.Filter;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;
import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker;


public class SessionHandleApp implements BundleActivator {

    public static final String DSNAME = "jdbc/Oracle";
    public ServiceTracker st;

    @Override
    public void start(final BundleContext bc) throws Exception {
        debug("Activator started");


        Filter filter = bc.createFilter("(&" + "(" + Constants.OBJECTCLASS
                + "=" + DataSource.class.getName() + ")" + "(jndi-name="
                + DSNAME + ")" + ")");
        st = new ServiceTracker(bc, filter, null) {

            @Override
            public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) bc.getService(reference);
                try {
                    debug(ds.getConnection().toString());

                SessionHandle sh = new SessionHandleImpl();
                                sh.setDataSource(ds);
                    ServiceRegistration registerService = bc.registerService(SessionHandle.class.getName(), sh, new Properties());

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }

                return super.addingService(reference);
            }

            @Override
            public void removedService(ServiceReference reference,
                    Object service) {
                super.removedService(reference, service);
            }

        };
        st.open();                
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext bc) throws Exception {
        boolean ungetService = bc.ungetService(bc.getServiceReference(SessionHandle.class.getName()));
        st.close();
    }

    private void debug(String msg) {
        System.out.println("JDBCBundleActivator: " + msg);
    }

}
```

This solution works but legacy aproach with using a database driver classname to configure JDBC does not work well in OSGi.

How I must write a bundle with an activator that initializes the datasource and offers it as a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused. The above code is not using JDBC driver. It is using JDBC datasource as a service. In GlassFish, the easiest way to create a DataSource service is to use GlassFish administration operation like "asadmin create-jdbc-resource with a JNDI name." Then GlassFish automatically registers it as a DataSource OSGi service with a registration property jndi-name=YourSuppliedJndiName.

Comment: Yes, the above code does not use JDBC driver directly which was your primary concern, so it's correct in that regard. It's a different issue that there are some parts of the code which looks suspicious. e.g., you are registering a new SessionHandle service when the desired DataSource service is made available, but you are not unregistering it when the said service vanishes. Ideally, you should make registerService as a field of the service tracker so that you can unregister it in removedService() method of the service tracker.

Comment: Would you correct the code? Upload it at www.http://pastebin.com/ I can create a simple Activator but for this I don't have enough knowledge to make it correct.

Answer (score 1):

You may check [Gemini DBAccess project](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/dbaccess/), it exports a `DataSourceFactory` as an OSGi Service, so you can just use it.

Comment: I found this example from Gemini DBAccess: http://pastebin.com/S8rvbNhZ I found it hard to implement it with Apache Felix. I don't have enough practice with OSGI.